# Cant configure ingress on gcloud properly

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy a simple app on google cloud. I am testing the gitlab kluster integration.
Here is my yaml k8:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service
  namespace: "my-service"
  labels:
    run: service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    run: "service"
  ports:
  - port: 9000
    targetPort: 9000
    protocol: TCP
    name: http

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: service-api
  namespace: "my-service"
  labels:
    run: service

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service-v1
  namespace: "my-service"
  labels:
    run: service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: service
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: service-api
      containers:
        - name: service
          image: "gcr.io/test/service:latest"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: test
              mountPath: /usr/test
      volumes:
        - name: test
          emptyDir: {}

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "service-ingress"
  namespace: "my-service"
  labels:
    run: service
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: service
          servicePort: 9000
```

If I log into the pod I can curl the service on the nodePort designed IP, but if I try to hit the ingress address I just get a error:

I am not sure why there are 2 backend services on the loadbalancer that is created automatically, the one that points to my app shows as unhealthy

[load balancer backends[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GakRc.png)

Comment: can you check if health check got configured in the load balancer ?

Comment: Hi @ArghyaSadhu
It did, gcloud create it automatically when I create the ingress.
    Description    Default kubernetes L7 Loadbalancing health check.
    Path    /
    Protocol    HTTP
    Port    30460
    Proxy protocol    NONE
    Logs    Disabled
    Interval    60 seconds
    Timeout    60 seconds
    Healthy threshold    1 success
    Unhealthy threshold 10 consecutive failures

Comment: try addig readiness probe in your pod spec

Comment: Does it work from the node that the pod is deployed? Try curl'ing it from this node.

Comment: Hi @ArghyaSadhu, defining the readiness probe to the deployment file solved the problem.
Thanks you

Comment: Hi @KFC_ it was working from inside the node, the ingress was not sending the requests because the health check was not working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define [readiness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) in your pod spec because GKE ingress controller picks up health check from the readiness probe.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service-v1
  namespace: "my-service"
  labels:
    run: service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: service
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: service-api
      containers:
        - name: service
          image: "gcr.io/test/service:latest"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 3
            periodSeconds: 3
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: test
              mountPath: /usr/test
      volumes:
        - name: test
          emptyDir: {}
```